# HashCode for a CSR

Tags: openssl, certificate, sha1, public-key-encryption, csr

I have generated a P10 certificate and a Certification applicant document using a software(Dakota). The document contains a hash code. This hash code is supposed to be an SHA1 hash of the public key of the certificate.

To verify this i converted the P10 certificate to a PEM format certificate using openssl.
I then extracted the public key of this PEM certificate using openssl.
On applying the SHA1 hash algorithm on this public key I obtain a hashcode different from the one which is auto generated by the Dakota Software.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible issues here.  First, is your public key in PEM format?  If so, you will probably want to convert it to DER format before taking the SHA1 hash of it.

The 2nd possible issue is that the hash may not just be a hash of the public key.  It might be a hash of the public key, the distinguished name, and optionally, a set of certificate attributes.  Those components make up the CSR along with a signature.

I'm not sure why the hash is even there.  If the signature is part of the CSR, the hash really isn't needed.

Comment: I have converted the public key to DER format and also tried applying the hash to the complete CSR (both p10 format and PEM format). In all the cases the hash value generated doesnt match.

Comment: When you create a CSR, there is a hash taken of the distinguished name, public key, and other certificate attributes.  This hash is signed and the signature is included as part of the CSR.  If the hash you are talking about is the same hash that the signature is based on, you will not be able to just take the SHA1 hash of the CSR. You would have to open the CSR in a hex editor, remove the signature algorithm, the signature, and the first ASN.1 header bytes.  Then you can take the SHA1 hash of what's left over, and that would match the hash the signature is based on.